# How can I open another app using intents in ionic?

Tags: android, android-intent, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have tried the following markup but it does nothing

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title title-left">App Title</h1>
    <a class="button rate-me button-light" href="amzn://apps/here">Rate</a>
</ion-header-bar>
```

I thought may be it is because no app to handle the intent is installed. So, I  tried the following markup:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title title-left">App Title</h1>
    <a class="button rate-me button-light" href="http://link-to/app/here">Rate</a>
</ion-header-bar>
```

However, nothing happens on clicking on any of them on my android device. I can open the link when I try the app in my browser through. Do I need to add any permissions to make it work on android?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add `target='_system'` to the `<a>` element.
You will also need to install Cordova plugin InAppBrowser (`org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`).

Note however that if the app is missing, it will open the system web browser.

---

This opens the URL in the system web browser which asks the package manager for any apps using the URL scheme in their intent filters. `WebView` does not do it on its own. If you want to do it in `WebView` you need to override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

---

I just found out that the InAppBrowser does not handle `<a>` tags at all since Cordova 3.4.0 or so. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6747 So you will need to work around it. Or you can just specify `onclick="window.open('http://link-to/app/', '_system')"` in the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Install inappbrowser plugin

```
plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

or

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Step2: Insert the code in your view (html files)

```
<a class="item" onclick='window.open("https://www.google.com", "_system", "location=yes"); return false;'>Rate</a>
```