# Ionic: Launching external app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to launch an external app from within my Ionic app. For example, Instagram. I'm attempting this with [Lampaa's Startap](https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp)p plug in, and have followed a few previous examples with no success.

Here's the code inside the controller, called on an `ng-click=""`. I've tried to explain in comments what each step is attempting. I'd also like to add an app.availability to check if the app is installed, but couldn't work out how to do this either. Thanks!

```
$scope.onInstagramClick = function () {

// Check if
if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
// Using plugin com.lampa.startapp to launch the app for android
navigator.startApp.set({ 
    "package": "com.instagram.android",
}).start();

} else {
    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
               console.log('ios');
               navigator.startApp.set({ 
    "package": "instagram://",
}).start();
    } else {

         console.log('thisfailed.');
      };
    }
}
```

Comment: This was asked same time as yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176713/how-can-i-open-another-app-using-intents-in-ionic

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to target differently for iOS and Android. It also wouldn't launch an app using the in-app browser method in the answers there; I am specifically trying to utilise Lampaa's plug in

Comment: Do you have any error in console ?

Comment: I worked it out, will put up the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $scope.onInstagramClick = function () {


if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
var sApp = startApp.set("com.instagram.android");
sApp.start(function() { /* success */
    console.log("OK");
}, function(error) { /* fail */
    alert("no Instagram found");
});

} else {
    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
var sApp = startApp.set("instagram://");
sApp.start(function() { /* success */
    console.log("OK");
}, function(error) { /* fail */
    alert("no Instagram");
});

}
```

Tested on iPhone device. I had to do a few things in XCode to make it work. Namely, editing the `info.plist` of the application to allow external apps to open. 
This is done by adding `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` as another property inside `info.plist`, here you add "instagram" or whatever app as an "Item". Moreover, you'll need to make sure `App Transport Security Settings` has a boolean `Allow Arbitrary Loads` set to `YES`.