# Is there a possibility to redirect from my ionic2 app to an external app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to create a button, which when is clicked, an external application is opened. For example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitbit.FitbitMobile&hl=fr

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: i saw apps when launching external apps it wrote a url start with something like a package ex: quora.page1 ,may be the mobile OS handle this thing ... Just thought

Comment: It is possible that you have right, I have also seen anything like <a href="com.twitter.android" _target="system">. But how it works? How can I know which is the link of my app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) plugin from Apache Cordova. Its explained here in detail : https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/.

Hope this will help.

Comment: That would help me open a website link in an external browser, not open an external application.

Comment: Then this might be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177010/ionic-launching-external-app

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-app-launcher

I found the plugin during some googling. Hope it works.

Alternatively you can write your own plugin or make some native development.